# After the EVT_KILL_FOCUS event is executed, why does the blinking cursor in TextCtrl disappear?

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython, wxwidgets, wxtextctrl

I have a TextCtrl that has an EVT_KILL_FOCUS event that I use to validate the contents of the field, alerting the user when the value is wrong. After opening the MessageBox, I clear the field and i set the focus to the field that I left validate again. Problem is that the text blinking cursor that should appear inside the field disappears and I do not know why or how to fix it. This behavior causes the user to not know in which field the focus is positioned.

Does anyone have any ideas?

```
    ...
    self.txtCode = wx.TextCtrl(self, value='')
    self.txtCode.Bind(wx.EVT_KILL_FOCUS, self.__onTxtCodeKillFocus)
    self.txtCode.Bind(wx.EVT_CHAR_HOOK, self.__onTxtCodeTabKey)

def __validateTxtCodeContent(self):
    if self.txtCode.GetValue() == "":
        self.MessageBox(self, "Error Text", _("Warning"))
        return False
    return True

def __onTxtCodeKillFocus(self, event):
    event.Skip()
    if self.__validateTxtCodeContent() == False:
        self.txtCode.SetValue("")
        self.txtCode.SetFocus()

def __onTxtCodeTabKey(self, event):
    key = event.GetKeyCode()
    shift = event.ShiftDown()

    # 9 = TAB, 13 = ENTER
    if key != 9 and key != 13:
        event.Skip()
        return
    elif key == 9:
        if self.__validateTxtCodeContent():
            if shift:
                self.btnSave.SetFocus()
            else:
                self.txtDescription.SetFocus()
        else:
            self.txtCode.SetValue("")
            self.txtCode.SetFocus()
    else:
        return False
```

My validation is not only for empty field, but for example only empty field can be.

Important: In the EVT_CHAR_HOOK event this behavior does occurs too.

I tried to use this too:

```
self.txtCode.SetValue("")
self.txtCode.SetFocus()
self.txtCode.SetInsertionPointEnd() 
self.txtCode.Refresh()
```

But it did not work well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call `SetFocus()` from `KILL_FOCUS` handler. The most direct workaround is to use `CallAfter()` to call it slightly later, but even though this would "work", it's a very bad idea because you should not prevent the user from leaving the window -- and there is no way to completely prevent it from happening anyhow.

Just mark the code as being invalid (e.g. change its background), but don't try to retain focus when you're losing it.

P.S. Calling `MessageBox()` from a focus event handler may be a bad idea too in many circumstances, it's better to use `wxLogWarning()` or `CallAfter()` to delay showing the message box until the next event loop iteration.

Comment: I agree, in similar circumstances I simply change the background colour and  issue a `wx.MessageBox()` warning (not sure why you think that that is a bad idea, it works flawlessly, in my experience).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Vadim already said:

- You can do validation on the hitting "OK" button or when the dialog/panel is about to close
- You can use wxValidator to validate the user input depending on your task at hand.